# Dynamically generating Checkboxes but the event handler only works for the last one

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, dynamically-generated

Im trying to make dynamically checkboxes with a event handler but the event handler only works for the last one generated..

I have tried to change the position of my code. I have also tried to make more checboxes to se if that would make any difference.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < appointments.TotalCount; i++) {
    lstChckBox = new List<CheckBox>();
    box = new CheckBox();
    box.Tag = i;
    box.Text = appointments.Items[i].Subject;
    box.AutoSize = true;
    box.Location = new Point(KalenderLbl.Location.X, KalenderLbl.Location.Y + 
    KalenderLbl.Height + 5 + (i * 25));

    lstChckBox.Add(box);

    box.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chck_CheckedChanged);

    Controls.Add(box);
  }
}


void chck_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  foreach(CheckBox item in lstChckBox) {
    if (item.Checked == true) {
      Hide();
    }
  }
}
```

I want to know how to change the code so every checkbox have this event handler..

Comment: Push `lstChckBox = new List<CheckBox>();` *out* of the loop

Comment: Instead of `lstChckBox` use `(sender as CheckBox)`.

Comment: Thanks @DmitryBychenko It Works!!

Comment: Do anyone have any idea how to get the appointment body from the item wich is checked to an string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do the trick as suggested by Dmitry Bychenko.

```
var lstChckBox = new List<CheckBox>( );
for (int i = 0; i < appointments.TotalCount; i++)
{
    box = new CheckBox( );
    box.Tag = i;
    box.Text = appointments.Items[i].Subject;
    box.AutoSize = true;

    box.Location = new Point( KalenderLbl.Location.X, KalenderLbl.Location.Y + KalenderLbl.Height + 5 + ( i * 25 ) );
    lstChckBox.Add( box );

    box.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler( chck_CheckedChanged );

    Controls.Add( box );
}

void chck_CheckedChanged( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    foreach (CheckBox item in lstChckBox)
    {
        if (item.Checked == true)
        {
            Hide( );
        }
    }
}
```

I would also suggest to shorten and simplify parts of your code, like.

```
var lstChckBox = new List<CheckBox>( );
var InitialYPosition = KalenderLbl.Location.Y + KalenderLbl.Height + 5;
for (int i = 0; i < appointments.TotalCount; i++)
{
    box = new CheckBox( ) {
        Tag = i,
        Text = appointments.Items[i].Subject,
        AutoSize = true,
        Location = new Point( KalenderLbl.Location.X, InitialYPosition + ( i * 25 ) )
    };
    lstChckBox.Add( box );

    box.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler( chck_CheckedChanged );

    Controls.Add( box );
}
```

Minimizing the code and avoiding the using of box.Property to set some data that is going to be set none the less.